# UWP community toolkit carousel exception

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-community-toolkit

I have the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Uid="Favorites" Style="{StaticResource SectionHeaderTextBlock}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <toolkitControls:Carousel x:Name="TemplatesCarousel" Style="{StaticResource CarouselControl}" ItemsSource="{Binding PaymentTemplates}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplatesDataTemplate}">
         <toolkitControls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
             <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
         </toolkitControls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
     </toolkitControls:Carousel>
 </Grid>
```

Where DataTemplate is the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplatesDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <!-- TODO: correct binding names -->
        <Ellipse Visibility="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}" Width="{StaticResource EllipseDimension}" Height="{StaticResource EllipseDimension}">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TemplateName}" FontSize="{StaticResource TextSize}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>`
```

The problem is when I try to run the application, it always gives me the same error. I know that this problem is in XAML, but I have checked literally everything. I also tried to set up ItemSource for carousel using code-behind, but it has no positive impact.

[image]

Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

P.S. I have the message of the exception from the output window, in case it can help.

> Message = "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Comment: Why are you using `x:DataType` with `Binding`?

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake. I have fixed it, but it did not resolve the issue anyway.

Comment: I have tested your code that I can not reproduce your issue. It seems the issue is not related to XAML. You should be able to give us more detail.

Comment: Well, thanks for your reply! I guess, I have fixed it. I just reinstalled the Community toolkit from the NuGet and it resolved the issue! I do not  know for sure where the problem is, but it is gone.